# Exe wrapped JavaFX Application (with Launch4J) doesn't open other stages

Tags: java, javafx, launch4j

I have wrapped my JavaFX application with Launch4J. The main stage of the app opens up and runs just fine (with the exception of the CSS not loading) but it does not open up other stages which I use for settings and such.

Launch4J config:

```
 <launch4jConfig>
   <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
   <headerType>gui</headerType>
   <jar>C:\Users\xxx\IdeaProjects\xxx\out\artifacts\xxx\xxx.jar</jar>
   <outfile>C:\Users\xxxx\TEST\bin\test.exe</outfile>
   <errTitle></errTitle>
   <cmdLine></cmdLine>
   <chdir>.</chdir>
   <priority>normal</priority>
   <downloadUrl></downloadUrl>
   <supportUrl></supportUrl>
   <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
   <restartOnCrash>false</restartOnCrash>
   <manifest></manifest>
   <icon></icon>
   <jre>
     <path>C:\Users\xxx\TEST\jre1.8.0_25</path>
     <bundledJre64Bit>false</bundledJre64Bit>
     <bundledJreAsFallback>false</bundledJreAsFallback>
     <minVersion>1.8.0_01</minVersion>
     <maxVersion>1.8.0_25</maxVersion>
     <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
     <runtimeBits>64/32</runtimeBits>
   </jre>
 </launch4jConfig>
```

Works fine when run off compiler. Any reasons as to why other stages work?

Are there any better tools for packaging JRE's with JavaFX apps? Ones that don't need to be installed would be good because I am limited by enterprise access controls and such.

Comment: Why didn't you first try the tools that come with the JDK and are explicitly created for beeing used with JavaFX?

Comment: @mipa still doesn't open stages with the JavaFX Packager Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was FXML file path was declared as:

```
 'src/etc/etc'
```

Changing this to just

```
'/etc/etc'
```

Seems to work. I guess it is to do with when its compiled it doesn't have the src folder.